# Sinatra / HAML - how can I use html_safe functionality?

Tags: sinatra, haml, html-entities

I am getting this error.

This is the line causing the problem; I'm trying to display html entities.

%p= html_escape("&#10004")

I understand html_safe is not available in Sinatra. What can I use to replace that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Haml docs (http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)

You can do this:

```
&= "&#10004"
```